# Android Plugin for Eclipse problem

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I am using a laptop with Windows 7 Home Prem x64. I have installed Java JDK1.6.0_18 and Eclipse Gallileo. I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Android SDK with several Platforms loaded and a AVD defined. I can install the Android Eclipse plugin from the remote site stated in the instructions. The plugin installation performs without any errors and I can verify that the plugins are indeed installed. My problem begins when I go to Windows -> Preferences, there is no Android section to configure. And when I go to File -> New -> Project, there is no Android Project to choose.

I have uninstalled the plugin and reinstalled at least 10 times, trying different things and still no luck. I originally had the 64 bit version of the JDK installed, but removed it and installed the 32 bit version.

Has anyone heard of this type of problem? Is it because I am using Windows 7?

Thanks for any help.
tbneff

Comment: It's not a Win7 issue, at least there isn't a universal one.  I'm using galileo, Win7x64 with no trouble.  Do you have the DDMS perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the following and have it manually install from there:

Help -> Software Updates -> Add site -> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

I didn't see it on the website regarding if the ADT or the SDK is not compatible with Windows 7.

When you said you installed the 32-bit version, did you get it working or not at all?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have space in your Eclipse or Android SDK path? do not use spaces in path. I had similar problems and that's because spaces.

Comment: This seems to have been the problem. I deleted my Eclipse install and re-installed in a location where the directory path had no spaces, e.g., from C:\Program Files (x86)\ to C:\Development\. I also moved the Android SDK under the same directory structure. Now I can see the Android 'stuff' in Eclipse. Thank you so much to everyone who answered my question and thank you Cahya for the heads up.

Comment: Had the same problem when I updated to the latest SDK in 32 bit Windows 7.  Moving the eclipse directory from C:\Program Files\java to the root of C: drive fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome, @tbneff & @dfjacobs. Even in my XP, spaces cause problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my Mac, and found out what my problem was. When I was futzing around with stuff I had renamed the config.ini file in the eclipse/configuration folder. When I renamed it back to config.ini and restarted eclipse everything Android was back in the menus for me.